# Tournament HITs on Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: mechanicalturk, mturk

New to Amazon Mechanical Turk (MTurk) and experimental research in general, so hopefully there's an obvious answer to this question I'm not just not seeing due to lack of experience:

I am trying to have groups of 5 workers complete Task 1 simultaneously. The difficulty of Task 1 will be randomly assigned such that 1 worker will have a much easier Task 1 than the other 4. The worker performing the best on Task 1 will receive feedback letting them know that they have won, whereas the other 4 workers will be told that they have lost. All 5 workers will then complete Task 2 before finishing the HIT. I can see this presenting the following problems:

1. The HIT must group workers together and start simultaneously
2. The HIT must randomly assign an "easy" Task 1 to a single worker within said group
3. The HIT must provide feedback based on performance relative to other workers

Are any or all of these features possible to implement within MTurk? I have built the survey in Qualtrics and have zero programming experience, so I'm looking more for settings I can activate within MTurk that will allow for these features than coding solutions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this many years from now needing help, I did find a solution called SMARTRIQS that has proven quite user-friendly and helpful.

I highly recommend checking it out if you need to run interactive experiments on Qualtrics with zero programming knowledge:

https://smartriqs.com/

Comment: Looks like spam or self-promotion.

Comment: I can certainly see how it could come across that way; person makes an account, asks a single question, then answers said question themselves. I'm just glad I found a solution on my own since no one else was able to provide one in the 2+ weeks the initial post was up. I hope that future readers find this thread useful either way.